# Headphones output for Sony Alpha A77

Tags: microphone, headphones, xlr

I have AKG D5S super-cardial dinamic XLR microphone.

I have 20 meters XLR female->3.5mm angled stereo cable

I have Sony A77 camera

All this works well recording the sound.

There is Sony A99, which has a headphones output on the camera.

I also have Shure XLR-2-USB amplifier, and this amplifier is two fingers size, Zero latency and has a headphones output. It works well if I connect my microphone to computer.

My questions is that - maybe there is some things like:

**XLR female to 3.5mm converter WITH heaphones output**

> (so 3.5mm 2 signal outputs, and one XLR input. One 3.5mm stereo output
>   will go to camera, the other one is to connect my headphones)

Or maybe small XLR amplifier, with XLR input and XLR output or 3.5mm output.

Or maybe there is 3.5mm amplifier with battery with 3.5mm output.

Any of these is fine.

Because I can figure out the way how I can hear the sound realtime.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying Sony external 5" Portable screen with Headphone output and 15 meters of lighweight directional HDMI cable from Amazon. Works well, records realtime. If you're doing PRO interviews, you need to go away from your camera and have external screen (makes in color focused place when PEAKING on), and you're also getting a headphone output as well. AJHenderson solution to use VGA+Audio converter from HDMI works well too (additional miniHDMI->HDMI adapter required), but I use mostly external screen way - because when I decide to do professionally I do it in full, otherwise I take a minimal setup.

http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666479348

Comment: Yeah, if you need the external screen, then that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the audio off the HDMI output.  Something like [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1151?gclid=CI3qgILi17gCFcuj4AodUjcAbA) will do the job nicely.

Comment: "this" is HDMI -> VGA.
I have miniHDMI->HDMI adapter, it's fine.
But I want to output sound.
So I probably want to search for:
HDMI->3.5mm Stereo adapter.
I can't find such as that thing in Amazon, but maybe I use wrong keywords to search.

Comment: Oh Sorry for my mistake. I just saw it has a 3.5mm output. This might be the ANSWER. But I'm NOT SURE if my A77 outputs VIDEO+SOUND via HDMI. Maybe it is just VIDEO.

Comment: @KestutisITDev - it should do both.  I actually found that device by doing a search for how to get headphone output from your camera over HDMI and that came up as a result.

Comment: I already ordered that product :). Will check this Friday/Sat. And if it works, I will mark your answer as 'accepted'.

Comment: Just to add something, my Sony A37 gives sound out thru HDMI cable and so I hear the video sound in television, but the sound also comes out the camera's speaker at the same time. I did not see it as a problem, so I never went to check Menu settings if I could disable camera speaker when HDMI cable is connected. Anyway confirmed that sound goes in HDMI.

Comment: @Esa Paulasto, on your camera sounds also goes out real-time while recording too?